# How to import custom bash functions to be used in PHP exec/system/etc?

Tags: php, bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a command-line application that will substitute a bunch of bash functions and manual work made by a team of developers. Currently, half of what we usually do is inside a `~/.functions` file that is sourced in the `~/.bash_profile` of each developer.

My command-line application is written in PHP, and for a while I would need to run some of those functions from inside my application. However, the following code would not work, the output says it cannot find the given function:

```php
exec('bash my_legacy_functions.sh');
exec('my_custom_legacy_function param1 param2');
```

I may be wrong, but I could understand that every `exec()` call runs a command in a separate process, meaning the functions would not be available for subsequents `exec()` calls. Is this right, and if yes, would it be possible to override this behaviour without having to bundle everything into one call?

Comment: `exec('foo1; foo2; foo3')` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it turns out the default shell was not bash, and on top of that source is not a common command in bash. I found by this [other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943723/102960) that the solution is something like:

```
function run($cmd) {
    exec("bash -c 'source my_legacy_functions.sh; $cmd'");
}
```